# Calling a custom function in jQuery event handler

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is the function I want to call (it definitely works I tested it):

```
function enableCategoryPopup(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    var buttonOffset = $(this).offset();
    $('.category-popup').css({
      top: buttonOffset.top + 10,
      left: buttonOffset.left +10
    });
    $('.category-popup').show(100);
  }
```

And this is where I want to call it:

```
$(document).on("mousedown", ".tab-links li:nth-child(2)", function(event) {
    if (event.which == 3) {
      enableCategoryPopup();
    }
  });
```

My custom function should be called as soon as I right click the specified element but it doesn't.
When I call `alert("x")` instead of `enableCategoryPopup()` it works, only my custom function doesn't get executed.

What am I doing wrong? How do I call my custom function?

Comment: Pass `event` object to function, `enableCategoryPopup(event);`

Comment: `enableCategoryPopup(event);` please :)

Comment: I'm afraid that doesn't seem to work :(

Comment: Post HTML and code in a snippet

Comment: FYI, in your code, the propagation of event stop at document level, not at event target (".tab-links li:nth-child(2)"). So describe how does your code isn't working???  BTW, if you stop mousedown event to any ancestor of `".tab-links li:nth-child(2)"`, this delegated event won't be fired

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try handling the event from within the enableCategoryPopup function

```
function enableCategoryPopup(event) {
    if (event.which == 3) {
        event.stopPropagation();
        var buttonOffset = $(this).offset();
        $('.category-popup').css({
          top: buttonOffset.top + 10,
          left: buttonOffset.left +10
        });
        $('.category-popup').show(100);
    }
  }

  $(document).on("mousedown", ".tab-links li:nth-child(2)", enableCategoryPopup);
```

Comment: awesome, happy to help

Comment: Ya but doesn't explain why OP's code wasn't working?!

Comment: my guess would be timing, or the function wasn't declared before the binding

Comment: Using referenced method as in your answer (which is the relevant way of doing it), this method has to be defined before (could be hoisted) unlike in OP's code. I'm not sure what you mean by timing but anyway, if that fixes OP's issue, get my vote... :)

Comment: thanks @A.Wolff, what I meant was that the click event was still happening before `enabledCategoryPopup` was able to `stopPropagation()`. OP could have also tried `event.prevendDefault()`